# Grant access to a single file on github

Tags: git, github, translation, git-submodules, git-subtree

I'm just searching for a possibility to grant access to another developer to one single file in my git-repository. Is there any way except of submodules/subtrees?

It's just the localization-file which should be translated by an other person.

Looking forward for your responses!

Thanks!

Sebastian

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you cannot restrict access to single files on github.

You could either use a submodule or just have the other developer to send a pull request, if anything other than that file is changed you just reject it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible with a typical git workflow and might not be a good idea in the first place. We have several customers that tried to let their translators manage localization files which ended in chaos and/or corrupted files since these people typically don't know how to edit these file types and are usually not familiar with git/scm.

Have you tried a SaaS solution for your problem? There are several solutions out there that manage translation files for developers. Our very own ([PhraseApp](https://phraseapp.com)) might be a good fit to your preferred language (Ruby/Rails).

Best wishes,
Manuel

Comment: Hey Manuel, thanks for your response. I will check out PhraseApp! Thanks!